# Writing values to excel using C#

Tags: c#, excel

I have to write values to excel through Selenium C#. I need to write 2 rows. I am not sure on ho wto go to the next row in excel with the below code.This is the code:

```
             SpreadsheetDocument spreadsheetDocument = SpreadsheetDocument.Create(@"C:\Excel\excel1.xlsx", SpreadsheetDocumentType.Workbook);
            WorkbookPart workbookPart = spreadsheetDocument.AddWorkbookPart();
            workbookPart.Workbook = new Workbook();
            workbookPart.Workbook.AppendChild(new Sheets());
            WorksheetPart worksheetPart = workbookPart.AddNewPart<WorksheetPart>();
            worksheetPart.Worksheet = new Worksheet(new SheetData());

            Sheet sheet = new Sheet
            {
                Id = workbookPart.GetIdOfPart(worksheetPart),
                SheetId = 1,
                Name = "testsheet"
            };
            spreadsheetDocument.WorkbookPart.Workbook.Sheets.Append(sheet);

            Row row = new Row();

            SheetData sheetData = worksheetPart.Worksheet.GetFirstChild<SheetData>();
            sheetData.Append(row);

            Cell cell1 = new Cell
            {
                CellReference = "A1",
                CellValue = new CellValue("SuPplier item CODE"),
                DataType = CellValues.String

            };
            row.Append(cell1);
           Cell cell2 = new Cell
            {
                CellReference = "A1",
                CellValue = new CellValue("SuPplier item CODE"),
                DataType = CellValues.String

            };
            row.Append(cell2);

           Cell cell3 = new Cell
            {
                CellReference = "A2",
                CellValue = new CellValue("SuPplier item CODE"),
                DataType = CellValues.String

            };
            row.Append(cell3);
```

How do I go to the next row in excel in the above code?
Please help.

Comment: Create a new instance of Row and append it to the sheet data.

Comment: I tried adding the below code but it doesn't work. Sorry I am new to programming  Row row1 = new Row();                                                                                                  SheetData sheetData1 = worksheetPart.Worksheet.GetFirstChild<SheetData>();                  sheetData1.Append(row1);

Comment: You should be able to append to the existing sheet data.  Do you see the first row in your generated spreadsheet?